# Auctioneer calling "Going once… going twice… sold!"

Tags: javascript, timer

I feel like the if-else combination isn't the most optimal and I'm also not sure if I need a loop

```
var Auktionator = function(){
var rennt = false;



this.versteigern = function(objekt){
        if(rennt === false){
        for(var i = 1; i<=4; i++){
            if(i === 1){
                setTimeout(function(){console.log(objekt + " zum ersten")},1000*i);
            }
            else if(i === 2){
                setTimeout(function(){console.log(objekt + " zum zweiten")},1000*i);
            }
            else if(i === 3){
                setTimeout(function(){console.log(objekt + " zum dritten")},1000*i);
            }
            else if(i === 4){
            setTimeout(function(){console.log(objekt + " verkauft!")},1000*i);

        }
         rennt = true;
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I would put the words into a list and use `i` as the index

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definetely not. The loop is useless (and un-optimizing) here.

As far as I can see, the index `i` is only used to calculate some constants' values. Realise that your original loop has the same effect than dropping off the loop and the `if`s clauses, and hard-code the values computed from `i`:

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log(objekt + " zum ersten")},1000);
setTimeout(function(){console.log(objekt + " zum zweiten")},2000);
setTimeout(function(){console.log(objekt + " zum dritten")},3000);
setTimeout(function(){console.log(objekt + " verkauft!")},4000);
```

Or, another valid alternative could be taking advantage of the resembling of the actions and generalize them by using data:

```
var messages=[" zum ersten", " zum zweiten", " zum dritten", " verkauft!"];
```

This would be more comprehensive and flexible, since it allows to add more messages without changing the logic a little.

**Update**

I recommend [RobH's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111084/auctioneer-calling-going-once-going-twice-sold/111089?noredirect=1#answer-111113), which is based upon arrays, and works fine.

Comment: makes alot of sense! thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks, but I've realised that there is another better way. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @RobH No, you are wrong. My loop is zero-based: `(var i=0;i<messages.length;i++)`, so it never reaches i==4.

Comment: Isn't the problem that the `i` variable is called in a "callback" function within `setTimout` and that by the time the function is executed, `i` will be out of scope?

Comment: @TopinFrassi - No. The i variable iscaptured, it's just that the loop executes to the end, setting i to 4 before the first setTimeout function is called. C# had the same behaviour for closures in a loop in .Net 4 but it was changed for .Net 4.5

Comment: @RobH Oooohhh I get it. What a twisted problem. Good catch!

Comment: @RobH Ho ho ho! Now I see it! The old closure evaluation problem! I've updated my post and credited you and TopinFrassi. Thanks both of you.

Comment: Your update still won't work as expected. It will print `verkauft!` 4 times.

Comment: @RobH You are right. :-( I deleted my update and recommended your answer. I can't delete my own post because it was selected as best. If the OP sets if off, I would delete it.

Answer (score 4):

Little Santi's answer has a bug because it is closing over the i variable in that asynchronous call in the for loop. Here's a simplified version of that code running in Chrome's console:

[image: Bug in the loop]

The approach is a good one, you just need to copy the value of the `i` variable. There are many tricks for that but you can improve readability by introducing another function `displayWithDelay`.

```
var messages=[" zum ersten", " zum zweiten", " zum dritten", " verkauft!"];
var displayWithDelay = function (message, delay) {
    window.setTimeout(function() { console.log(message); }, delay);
}

for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
{
    displayWithDelay(messages[i], 1000*(i+1));
}
```